# react router dynamic urls not working when running build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using create-react-app version of react.

React-router-dom stops functioning correctly for dynamic urls when I run the build folder in my browser.

it works fine however when run from react-scripts start

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
      <Route path="/blog/" component={Blog} exact />
      <Route path="/blog/:id" component={BlogPost} />
      <Route path="/portfolio/:id" component={PortfolioItem} />
      <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} exact />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} exact />
      <Route path="/services/:id" component={Service} />
```

Both /blog/:id and /services/:id give a 404 all other routes work 100% as normal, fetch is working with my api content, images display, everything works on the static urls.

To repeat this only happens when running the build.

Comment: Does `/portfolio/:id` work?

Comment: I think you will have to provide more code, because technically this should work on create-react -app and I don't think there's any reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe replace `"/blog/"` to `"/blog"`. and you can use `<Route exact path.../>`.
The services need id? if not sure write `"/services/:id?"`.
Sure it `"/services/:id"` and not `"/service/:id"`?

Answer (score 0):

make a file name it ".htaccess" and put this inside that:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
  </IfModule>
```

if again it was not working, check your package.json to set **homepage** propery to your main url.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** Since you clarified you're running a HTTP server, I've erased my old answer and added an alternative:

The issue is likely the setup of your Apache server. You could try using hash history, if that works we will be sure the issue is with Apache:

```
import { createHashHistory } from "history"
import { Route, Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom"

const customHistory = createHashHistory()

...

<Router history={customHistory}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
    <Route path="/blog/" component={Blog} exact />
    <Route path="/blog/:id" component={BlogPost} />
    <Route path="/portfolio/:id" component={PortfolioItem} />
    <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} exact />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} exact />
    <Route path="/services/:id" component={Service} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

**Note:** If that works but you don't want to use hash history, you'll have to properly set up your Apache server as a reverse proxy. Instructions for that can be [read here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

Comment: I'm running apache locally, all the pages work fine apart from those.2 dynamic urls

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all, the compiled build should run as static content fine

Comment: @Webber He didn't specify he was already running a web server.

Comment: And actually no, there are different restrictions when it comes to accessing files straight from the HTML file and from a server through either HTTP or HTTPS. More here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-html

Comment: Ah you're right @TelmoTrooper. Still makes this answer a random guess that's not really related to the question. As the OP stated (twice) `this only happens when running the build`

Comment: @InspireDigitalShropshire Is your Apache server configured as a reverse proxy? My guess is that it's not properly routing the calls to your React app. If you don't want to bother with that, using hash history should also solve the issue (because in that case all requests will be resolved by React).

Comment: I edited my answer to suggest attempting to use hash history as to find out if the issue is really in your Apache configuration.

Comment: I also attempted run build with the node http server and the issue remains