# URL Params in React-router-dom only work locally, but returns blank page after running build

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a React app where the user can cancel his newsletter subscription by typing `/cancelar/newsletter/email` and it sends a delete request to the API (if the e-mail exists in the newsletter list) and informs the user, it works perfectly in the way I want locally, but after running build, the same URL run just returns a white page, as if it does not exist, but the rest of the application keeps working normally, take a look the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../Components/Home/Home';
import CurrencySearcher from '../Components/CurrencySearcher/CurrencySearcher';
import Calculator from '../Components/Calculator/Calculator';
import Suggestion from '../Components/Suggestion/Suggestion';
import Graphic from '../Components/Graphic';
import CancelNewsletterSubscription from '../Components/CancelNewsletterSubscription';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter >
            <Switch>
                <Route path = "/" exact component = {Home} />
                <Route path = "/buscar" component = {CurrencySearcher} />
                <Route path = "/sugerir" component = {Suggestion} />
                <Route path = "/calculadora" component = {Calculator} />
                <Route path = "/graficos" component = {Graphic} />
                <Route path = "/status"/>
                <Route path = "/cancelar/newsletter/:email" component = {CancelNewsletterSubscription} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter >
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

This is the Component that this URL returns:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import Navbar from '../Navbar';
import api from '../../api/config';
import './styles.css';
import letterIcon from '../../assets/envelope-fill.svg';
import unexpectedError from '../Toasters/unexpectedError';
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

const CancelNewsletterSubscription = () => {

    const params = useParams();
    const [ userEmail, setUserEmail ] = useState();
    const [cancelSubscriptionStatus, setCancelSubscriptionStatus] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setUserEmail(params.email);

        api.delete(`/newsletter/cancel/${params.email}`).then((result) => {

            if(result.status === 200){
                console.log('Apagado com sucesso');
                setCancelSubscriptionStatus(true);
            }
            
        }).catch(err => {

            if(err.response.status === undefined || err.response.status === null){
                console.log(err);
                unexpectedError();
            }
  
            if(err.response.status === 404){
         
                setCancelSubscriptionStatus({
                    status: false,
                    error: 'non existing e-mail on newsletter list',
                    code: 404
                })
            } 
         
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div >
            <Navbar/>   
            <ToastContainer/>
            <div className = "container" >

                {cancelSubscriptionStatus === true ? (
                    <div className = "generalTextArea"> <br/>  <br/>  <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>  <br/> <br/>              
                    <img height = {50} src = {letterIcon} alt = "letterIcon" id = "letterIcon" />
                    <h1>Assinatura da Newsletter cancelada com sucesso para o e-mail <i className = "userEmail">{userEmail}!</i></h1>
                    <h5>Você não receberá mais mensagens sobre as novidades do conversor de moeda.</h5>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <div className = "generalTextArea"> <br/>  <br/>  <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>          
                    <img height = {50} src = {letterIcon} alt = "letterIcon" id = "letterIcon" />
                    <h1>E-mail não encontrado na lista de newsletter, tente novamente ou <a id = "backToHomeLink" href = "/">volte para a tela de início</a>.  </h1>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                )}

                  
          
            </div>
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default CancelNewsletterSubscription;
```

As you can see in the code and the image below, I have already set the URL passing email as a parameter once it will be dynamic based on the current user e-mail

[How it looks locally (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydwdh.png)

And this is how it looks in production running the built version

[How it looks in production (not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92SHS.png)

Already tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762590/react-router-dynamic-urls-not-working-when-running-build) and tried to replace BrowserRouter with HashRouter but the issue persists, dynamic URL works locally but not in the built version. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would try to build the app, and run the built app locally, to make sure that the error is with the build of the current version of the code. It is strange if it works in the development version and not the built version.

Comment: @ArneHugo Done, I ran the build of the project once again and served to see locally how it goes, and it had the same result: https://prnt.sc/1xzr9qu

Comment: Ok, interesting. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: There it goes! https://prnt.sc/1xzyoy9

Comment: Do you get the same errors when running the development bundle? Or is there one that only happens in the production bundle? If so, start by figuring out what causes it.

Comment: Only in production bundle. I searched for some articles about it and I changed the homepage URL on package.json for the one of my production website and the issue now seems fixed and works perfectly, although I don't really know why.